# Polyomial equations with two unknows

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

$a,b,c>0$ are given constants, $0<x<y$ are unknown, how to solve the following equations?
$$
\begin{cases}
a=b(y-x) \\
c=\frac{2}{3}a(y^3-x^3)-\frac{1}{2}b(y^4 - x^4) +\frac{2}{3} b x(y^3 -x^3)
\end{cases}
$$

This problem  originated from  a concrete issue, I am sure  for all $a,b,c>0$ there are $0<x<y$ solving the equations. But I don't know how to solve it. So, I ask help here. Thanks for any hint or answer.

Comment: The same way you solve any system of equations really: use the first equation to solve for $y$ in terms of $x$, then plug into and try to solve the second equation.

Comment: Is the second equation right? The first term on the RHS has degree one less than the others.

Comment: You get $$y = \frac{a}{b} + x$$ from first equation. Now substitute this in the second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the 1st equation, you will get
$$y = \frac{a}{b} + x$$

You can then substitute this equation into the second equation to solve for $x$, which is just a cubic equation in terms of $x$.

Comment: Although there is   a lot of calculation, but it is right. Thanks.

Comment: @lanse7pty. I even think that it reduces to a quadratic equation in $x$.